# Opened previously functional basic xml code -- no longer works

Tags: android, xml

I've search thoroughly but it doesn't appear that this is a common problem -- this may be increased by the fact that I'm still new and don't really know what to look for in this regard.

Regardless, the last time that I ran this code it worked fine however, now the display is simply white -- so even with the black writing it doesn't show up. Thank you very much for any help you can offer.

The xml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mocha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/price_mocha"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:text="Price of mocha"
        android:textColor="#060505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_mocha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:text="3.99"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does it show up in the design preview in AS?

Comment: No it doesn't, thanks for your answer!

Comment: `@drawable/background` might be `null`.